# CSS Media Query to target 1080 phones?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, screen-resolution

I'm looking for the correct CSS media query to target all phones (not tablets and larger) including 1080 phones such as the Sony Xperia Z.

Right now I'm using:

```
<link href='style/mobile.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen and (max-device-width: 767px)' />
```

That works for most devices, but in the Android Firefox Browser (not Chrome though strangely) the Xperia Z just gets the desktop site only.

I've tried searching but it seems no one is talking about these new very high-res phones, is there a new standard I should be adhering to?

Comment: If the devices are the same size, what sort of styles should apply to phones that shouldn't apply to tablets?

Comment: @cimmanon - Resolution doesn't necessarily dictate device size. I can see a situation where you'd want to target only phones because they're generally physically smaller, despite them sometimes being hi-res.

Comment: Yeah the full desktop site looks no way near as good as the mobile site on the Xperia Z, at least in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width` to target `CSS pixels`.

Do not forget [`viewport meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). Small devices with lots of pixel will still have a low CSS pixel count so it will just work.

Comment: The `viewport` meta tag will save your day across different browsers on the **same** device.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the width with resolution in your media query.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 767px) and (min-resolution: 300dpi) { … }
```

Comment: Thanks but that no longer works on a lower res device such as a Galaxy Nexus for instance (haven't tested on the Xperia yet)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find what you need in media queries. Phones and tablets have a big crossover in resolutions.

Here are the media features you can query according to the w3c...

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1

... none seem to be what you're looking for.

Unfortunately I don't know if a great way to deal with this, even the user-agent is of little help.